# Elasticsearch Scripting: updating every array element

Tags: elasticsearch

es version 5.4.1

I have a document like that

```
{'_id': 'AWUe4rSpgJ6eZRtHLwRC',
'_index': 'test',
'_score': 1,
'_source': {'data': [1, 2, 3, 4]},
'_type': 'test'}
```

and I am trying to add a number to all elements in data.

what I try is :

```
{  
    'query':{  
        'match_all':{}
    },
    'script':{  
        'inline': "for (int i=0;i<ctx._source.data.size();i++) {ctx._source.data[i]=ctx._source.data[i] + 1000000};",
        'lang':'painless'
    }
}
```

but I got

```
{'reason': "unexpected token [';'] was expecting one of [<EOF>]."}
```

I am new to painless. How can I make it current?

Comment: remove the last semicolon?

Comment: semicolon is a problem. if you check the `root_cause` in response you could actually see that it points to the last semicolon that should be removed